# Nginx redirect/rewrite url

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm using nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

I want to achieve the following

From:

```
https://www.testsite.com/mypath
```

to

```
http://myip:9990/index.html
```

This is what I have now, but it's not working for some reason

```
location /mypath{
    return 301 http://myip:9990/index.html;
}
```

I'm very new to ngnix, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^/mypath$ http://myip:9990/index.html last;
```

That responds with `HTTP 301`

Comment: I got this: This site can’t be reached myip took too long to respond. But if I visite http://myip:9990/index.html, I can view the page.